# Is there a way to detect if a user is forwarding their Google Apps mailbox

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am looking to find a way to detect if a user is forwarding their gmail box.I am using the latest Google Apps for Business setup. I was reading through the Google Admin SDK references and was unable to find anything that would work.

End goal: I want to scan all of my Google Apps users to detect people forwarding their mailboxes to another mailbox (internal or external)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this for an account using the free GAM tool with a simple command line. Example from the GAM documentation:

```
gam user alincoln show forward
```

GAM: https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM

Retrieving forwarding settings: https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/ExamplesEmailSettings#retrieving-forward-settings

Comment: You've lead me down a rabbit hole (in the best way) I've used GAM previously for this. I found this 

```client = gdata.apps.emailsettings.client.EmailSettingsClient(domain='example.com')
...

client.ClientLogin(email='adminUsername@yourdomain', password='adminPassword', source='your-apps')
client.RetrieveForwarding(username='venu')```